# axis2: serialization of wsdl2java generated objects

Tags: java, serialization, apache-axis

Using axis2's wsdl2java tool and a third-party wsdl I have generated service stub and supporting classes (data holders). Since there is a need to do post-processing of loaded data from a service, there is a need to serialize one of the data holder objects.

1) is there a standard axis2 tool / approach that can be used for the purpose?

2) since the data holder class does not implement Serializable interface what would be the easiest way of serializing the object into xml format with the ability to restore the original object?

Data binding option was used (-d jaxbri) and each field of the class in question is annotated with @XmlElement tag, e.g.:

```
@XmlElement(name = "ID", required = true)
protected String id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how I solved it:

1. axis2 generated java classes set (client side) had an object called ObjectFactory. Majority of its methods create JAXBElement objects with values of fields of the class holder
2. I had to implement a serializable wrapper class aSerializable for the class holder, such that it uses the ObjectFactory to create the JAXBElement objects for all the fields.
3. some external code uses the wrapper class to create an serializable object and writes it to the output stream.
4. on the receiving end:

   ASerializable aSerializable;
   A a;
   aSerializable= (ASerializable)in.readObject();
   a.setID((String)aSerializable.getID().getValue());
5. it still looks like extra work for the pre-annotated class serialization, but better than serializing into some text format and manual type checking during deserialization.